# Linux: Find all soft links that link to a specific directory

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, find, command

In Linux how do I find all soft links that link to a specific target directory or file?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find`'s `-lname` argument:

```
find . -lname linktarget
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` with `-samefile` and `-L` option, like this:

```
find -L -samefile TARGET
```

Answer (score 0):

What R1tschY sez, with an addition:

```
find -L -samefile TARGET \! -name TARGET
```

so `TARGET` won't be included in the result.  (The backslash is required in bash so the `!` won't be interpreted as a history directive.)