# Linux Shell: Verify whether a file exists and is a soft link?

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

How to verify whether a file or directory exist and is a symbolic link (soft link) on Linux?

I want to write a shell to do it.

Could you please give me some tips?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703989/linux-find-all-soft-links-that-link-to-a-specific-directory

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  If you want to determine if a given file is a symlink, the `file` command would tell you.  If you want to determine all the symlinks, use the `-l` option for `find`.

Comment: [link] http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-cn-hardandsymb-links/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-L` test option:

```
if [[ -L $file ]]; then
    echo "$file exists and is a symbolic link"
fi
```